# maxlength of input tag with type=text using html5 in android webview not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webview

i am able to enter more than specified maxlength of input tag with type=text using html5 in android webview. when lost focus/ blur, value will be trimmed to maxlength.

for example

```
<input type="text" maxlength="5" id="hahaha">

 value entered = abcdefghij
 on blur/lostfocus value displayed = abcde.
```

is there anyway that **restricts the user from entering** more characters than maxlength rather than **trimming content after user entered the content** . In IOS it is working fine.

Comment: @Blauharley type is text not number

Answer (score 3):

This problem probably is a bug in Android 4.1 version as you can see here [35264](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35264).
You can solve that with some Javascript:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="3" id="hahaha" onkeypress="if(this.value.length >= this.getAttribute('maxlength') return false;" />
```

or JQuery:

```
$(function() {
    max_length = Number($("#hahaha").attr("maxlength"));
    $("#hahaha").attr("onkeypress", "if(this.value.length >= max_length) return false;");
});
```

Comment: Dear @neliojrr onkeypress event is not getting fired, in android browser

Comment: Try to use `keyup` event and `substr` method. Look this solution: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/awns9167/1/)

Comment: @Nelio return false; is not restricting the user while entering more characters than maxlength...
Is there any way to restrict the user to type the characters if he exceeds more than maxlength

Comment: @Meena Take a look on this solution http://jsfiddle.net/awns9167/1/

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but as neliojrr mentioned you can correct this using javascript/jquery. However, I would be very tempted to make this much more generic:

```
$('input[maxlength]').on('keydown', function(event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.val().length > parseInt($this.attr('maxlength'), 10)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: event.preventDefault(); is not restricting the user while entering more characters than maxlength...
@paddybasi is there any way to restrict the user to type the characters if he exceeds more than maxlength

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @paddybasi it worked for me. Just one small correction. keydown event doesn't seem to be working in android. So we need to change the event to "textInput".

```js
$('input[maxlength],textarea[maxlength]').on('textInput', function (event) {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.val().length >= parseInt($this.attr('maxlength'), 10)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```