# How to set android web view content max length

Tags: android, webview

How to set android web view content max length

```
<WebView android:id="@+id/webview_preview"android:layout_width="match_parent"android:layout_height="wrap_content"android:scrollbars="vertical"android:visibility="visible"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

use maxlength or max.
you can take reference from these two questions:

[maxlength of input tag with type=text using html5 in android webview not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28198466/maxlength-of-input-tag-with-type-text-using-html5-in-android-webview-not-working/28199422)

[How can I limit possible inputs in a HTML5 "number" element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354975/how-can-i-limit-possible-inputs-in-a-html5-number-element)