# maxlength not working in browsers of android device but working in desktop browser

Tags: html

I am using `html5` to develop my views and came through a situation like `maxlength`,
I have a `FirstName` field with `maxlength` as `20` bytes.
So to achieve this I applied `maxlength` attribute to the input element of `FirstName`, which is working fine in desktop browser.

When I open my website in android device and test the `maxlength` of `FirstName` it is allowing me to enter characters which are more than the `Maxlength`.

Is there a way to restrict(not throwing validations instead stop the user to enter) the user, not to enter characters more than the maxlength especially in android  and IOS devices

After some google search, I found a javascript solution but even that did not work for me.
The solution which I tried is:

```
$('input[maxlength]').on('keydown', function (event) {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.val().length > parseInt($this.attr('maxlength'), 10)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [maxlength of input tag with type=text using html5 in android webview not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28198466/maxlength-of-input-tag-with-type-text-using-html5-in-android-webview-not-working)

Comment: But I tried that solution, that is also not working for me

Comment: all three of them? Maybe you could [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60868616/edit) your post to include what you tried so far without success

Comment: Yes I tried three of them, no solution is working in android, Sure I will edit my question..